# When the form is submitted with an error, the rendered url changes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have created a user signup page. When the user submits the form incorrectly, when displaying a validation error, it does not render on the same URL.

The signup form is located at this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/signup
```

I have added the following routes for the signup page:

```
resources :users
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
```

When I submit the form, the model validation shows up but the url redirects to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users
```

I want the user to remain at the same url after submitting the form.

```
http://localhost:3000/signup
```

This is my controller code:

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create

    @user = User.new(user_params) # Not the final implementation!

    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end
```

This is the beginning tag of my form:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: "create"}  do |f| %>
```

Comment: ` match '/signup',  to: 'users#update', via: 'put', as: 'signup' `

Comment: match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get', as: 'signup'  Not working :(

Comment: `get  'signup' => 'users#new', as: :signup` `put  'signup' => 'users#update', as: :signup` try to add those to your routes and delete the old one.

Comment: Now working it is.. I am working in 4.0

Comment: you can't use `match` with Rails 4. did you figure this out or you still need help?

Answer (score 5):

I'm working with Rails 5, but I suspect it's not too different conceptually.

In routes.rb:

```
get 'signup', to: 'users#new'
post 'signup', to: 'users#create'
resources :users
```

and in your form helper:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: signup_path  do |f| %>
```

Essentially, the reason why it's not working as described in your original post is because when the form posts ([rails 4.2 form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/form_helpers.html)), it's tied to `url: {action: "create"}`, which by default, according to the routes automatically generated for `resources :users`, is `post '/users', to: 'users#create` ([rails 4.2 routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/routing.html)). And by searching top down in routes.rb, it'll see this first and you end up with `http://localhost:3000/users`.

So, the changes I propose, should bind the form to post to the signup path instead which, in routes.rb, is seen as the second route entry.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that @Jaskaran's question is in regards to question 2 found at the bottom of Michael Hartle's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, [section 7.3.3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-signup_error_messages), so I will be answering in reference to that question:

> 2. How does the URL on the unsubmitted signup form (Figure 7.12) compare to the URL for a submitted signup form (Figure 7.18)? Why don’t they match?

To answer this question, we need to understand how routing works in a Rails application. Let's walk through what happens when you visit each page and make a submission.

Your main page (`home.html.erb`) contains a link to your signup page (`new.html.erb`). That link looks like this:

```ruby
<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
```

The `signup_path` is the part we are most interested in. `signup_path` is a [route helper](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) and essentially tells Rails that when someone clicks on that link, Rails should behave as if they just went to your `/signup` page. This is why the first URL you see (before submitting the form) shows `http://localhost:3000/signup`.

Now let's take a look at what happens when your form is submitted. According to the `new.html.erb` file, the form is contained within this Ruby code:

```ruby
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
. . .
<% end %>
```

You may remember from [7.2.2](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-the_form_html) that that Ruby code is actually rendered in HTML as:

```html
<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
. . .
</form>
```

What that is saying is that when the form is submitted, it will make a POST request to `/users` - and that's the URL that you are seeing in your browser.

We can better understand why this is if we first stop to think - where does `/users` route to? You can quickly check your routes by typing `bundle exec rake routes` in your console. You should see it listed there:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
users  GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
       POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
```

So any POST requests to `/users` will be routed to the `create` method of our `users_controller.rb`. If you're wondering why that is, it is because we added this line to our `routes.rb` file:

```ruby
resources :users
```

More details on that line can be found [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).